# Can we call @RequestMapping from Parent class path when Child class extends it in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

In an interview I was asked a question; Let's suppose you have a child controller that extends parent controller like in below code and we want to access the parent class `@RequestMapping` method. Can we do that? Is there any way?

When I tried below code and click on BaseHello link then I get the warning-
And if I write @Controller in Parent class then also the same warning is coming

```
May 09, 2020 2:18:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /Projectname/parent/hello
```

Parent.java

```
package com.practice;

@RequestMapping("/parent")
public abstract class Parent {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String world() {
        return "hellopage";
    }
}
```

Child.java

```
package com.practice;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/child")
public class Child extends Parent {
    @RequestMapping("/detail")
    public String info() {
        return "detailpage";
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<a href="parent/hello">BaseHello</a>
<a href="child/hello">ChildHello </a>
<a href="child/details">ChildDetails</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```java
//@RequestMapping("/parent") remove conflicts child path
public abstract class Parent {
    @RequestMapping("parent/hello")
    public String world() {
        return "hellopage";
    }}

@Controller 
// @RequestMapping("/child") // remove this, add child to the method, because abstract class already have one.
public class Child extends Parent {
    @RequestMapping("/child/detail")
    public String info() {
        return "detailpage";
    }}
```

Comment: I tried and it work fine when I access the BaseHello link but when I tried to access <a href="child/detail"> then it doesn't work and giving me "noHandlerFound" warning but why because if I am giving the correct path in index.jsp  as was in RequestMappping of Child controller then it should work.Right?

Comment: because `child/detail` becoming `parent/child/detail`

Comment: @Harry, I updated code example, maybe you can try again,  but if you have multiple parent URL or child URL, there will be duplicates